# How to edit file name under cursor in Vim/Gvim, when it starts with /cygdrive/ in Windows

Tags: vim, cygwin

With cygwin64 installed, and a separate Gvim 8.0.2 installation.
I can open a file on the bash prompt like this:

```
gvim /cygdrive/c/Temp/foo.txt
```

it works because my script uses `cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/Temp/foo.txt` to convert the path into its windows form, finally calling `gvim.exe C:\Temp\foo.txt`.

However in Gvim, when my cursor is on a line like this:

```
/cygdrive/c/Temp/foo.txt
```

and I type `<Ctrl-W> f`, I get this error text in Gvim:

```
E447: Can't find file "/cygdrive/c/Temp/foo.txt" in path
```

What must I do to get this working in a standard installation of Gvim under Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'includeexpr'` to modify the path found:

```
set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'/cygdrive/c','C:/','')
```

This will open `C:/Temp/foo.txt` instead.

See `:help gf`, `:help 'includeexpr'`

Comment: For this to work with multiple drive letters I have put this line into my _vimrc:   `set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\(^/cygdrive/\\)\\(.\\)','\\2:/','')`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what the [file-line plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184) does. You could develop a plugin for converting `/cygdrive/...` paths based on it quite easily.

Instead of hooking into `*:*` patterns, you'd use `/cygdrive/*`, and then convert the path, either in Vimscript (`substitute()`), or by invoking the external `cygpath` tool through `system()`.

The plugin then replaces the invalid current buffer with the corrected file name, and loads that instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I did try to convert on the fly from vim end. I gave up eventually as there were too many side effects -- like an improper filetype detection. The idea would be to listen to `BufCreate`and/or `BufNewFile` event to open the correct file and close the invalid one. Here is a [plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/fixfilename.vim) that tries to correctly open `file:lineno` -- but with side effects :(

As most of my use cases were to open filenames in the quickfix windows, I first came up with a [cygwin compiler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=722), then I moved it into [build-tools-wrapper](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

Create hardlinks to make these /cygdrive/c/path == /c/path == c:/path equivalent in NTFS:

```
start > cmd > 
mkdir c:\cygdrive
mklink /D c:\cygdrive\c c:\
mklink /D c:\cygdrive\d d:\

cd c:\cygwin64
mklink /D c /cygdrive/c
mklink /D d /cygdrive/d
```

and as above in vimrc for gf

```
set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'^/cygdrive/\\(\\w\\)/','\\1:/','')
```

test:

```
                 echo 123 > c:/x
C:\cygwin64\>    ls -al c:/x /cygdrive/c/x /c/x
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ad None  6 Mar 26 21:47 /c/x
-rw-r--r-- 1 a  Users 6 Mar 26 21:47 /cygdrive/c/x
-rw-r--r-- 1 a  Users 6 Mar 26 21:47 c:/x
```